# How can I use state values as Meta tag content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, meta-tags

I want a page link to preview an image and titles when shared. Using Nextjs Head Component for that purpose. I fetch all the necessary details on page load and use them as contents of the meta attributes.

```
let campaign = this.state.campaignDetails;
<React.Fragment>
            <Head>
                <title>{campaign!==null && campaign.title}</title>
                <meta name="title" content={campaign!==null && campaign.title}/>
                <meta name="description" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.description : undefined}></meta>
                <meta name="image" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.image : undefined}></meta>

                <meta property="og:title" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.title : undefined}/>
                <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
                <meta property="og:site_name" content="website"/>
                <meta property="og:url" content="https://website.com/"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.image : undefined}/>
                <meta property="og:description" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.description : undefined}/>

                <meta name="twitter:card" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.image : undefined}/>
                <meta name="twitter:title" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.title : undefined}/>
                <meta name="twitter:description" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.description : undefined}/>
                <meta name="twitter:site" content="@website"/>
                <meta name="twitter:image" content={campaign!==null ? campaign.image : undefined}/>
                <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@website"/>
            </Head>
            <div></div>
 </React.Fragment>
```

The above approach doesn't do as I require. I used react helmet to no avail.
What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, first add a console.log on the page and check when the component is first rendered what is the state value is, whether it showing the values or showing undefined or null? if it is undefined or null then the problem lies there.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replying. Yes, the values are shown in the console and used in the main render body. But doesn't get included in meta tag contents.

Comment: Are you fetching the metadata on the client-side or server-side? Please show the code of the full component.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a complete code sample to be able to reproduce the problem. Supposing that you are actually **returning** a Next.js [**Head**](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) component the issue is most likely with your campaign variable, so be sure to check that campaign is not null or undefined as MD M Nauman mentioned.

```
import Head from 'next/head';

function YourPage() {
  const { campaign = {} } = this.state.campaignDetails; // Make sure this is not null or undefined!
  const { description, image } = campaign;

  const seo = { description, image };

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
        <meta name="description" content={seo.description} />
        <meta name="image" content={seo.image} />
        {/* ... */}
      </Head>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default YourPage;
```

You can also check out **[next-seo](https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo)** maybe it helps you.